# ‘glDispatchCompute’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, opengl, ubuntu, netbeans, graphics

error: ‘glDispatchCompute’ was not declared in this scope

I have been working for a month on my setup doing fine. But I have problems using the compute shader. Netbeans says glDispatchCompute isn't declared even though I can Ctrl+click it and see it lying in glew.h, which is included.

OS: Ubuntu 12.10
IDE: Netbeans 8.0

This is what i get from GL_VERSION and whatnot:

GL Vendor : ATI Technologies Inc.
GL Renderer : AMD Mobility Radeon HD 5000 Series
GL Version (string) : 4.4.12874 Compatibility Profile Context 14.10.1006.1001
GL Version (integer) : 4.4
GLSL Version : 4.30

I have tried including anything I can think of:

```
#include <GL/glew.h> 
#include <GL/gl.h> 
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glcorearb.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/glext.h>

// ... //

glDispatchCompute(32, 32, 1);
```

I have intellisense up to GL_VERSION_4_5 defined in glew.h
I can compile and link shaders with GL_COMPUTE_SHADER and #version 430
I have the capability GL_ARB_compute_shader
-lGLEW -lGL is added to command line

glDispatchCompute requires 4.3
https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glDispatchCompute.xhtml

I thought maybe it's because I only have 14.1 Catalyst, but I saw someone use glDispatchCompute on 13.xx.

My card's and driver's capability in detail:
http://feedback.wildfiregames.com/report/opengl/device/Mobility%20Radeon%20HD%205000

I can make regular 3D programs that use OpenGL, just not with compute shader so far.

What am I missing?

EDIT:

After update to glew 1.11.0 I get:
undefined reference to `__glewDispatchCompute'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Are you using the latest version of GLEW?

Comment: That's a compile-time error, by the way. It's got nothing to do with your installed hardware / software. Basically your headers are out of date.

Comment: @glampert, I downloaded 1.11.0 from glew.sourceforge and now I get this instead: "undefined reference to `__glewDispatchCompute' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status". So the call to glDispatchCompute checks out but it fails further down the line.

Comment: I ran glewinfo and saw it stops at GL_VERSION_4_2, so glDispatchCompute isn't even in there. Do i only have 4.2 after all?

Comment: @Kelkka: As Andon M. Coleman pointet out, those compile/link time errors are totally independent on the capatibilities of your GPU. Maybe you updated the headers now, but still link to the old version of the library?

Comment: @derhass Yes, the functions are defined in glew.c. I am pretty sure I got the newest libs since I downloaded 1.11, installed them and in usr/lib they were edited at the time I updated, I got libglew.so.1.11.0, libglew.a, libglew.so in there. I solved it for now by clipping the functions I need from a glew.c straight into my own files. Glewinfo says i have GLEW version 1.8.0, which is too little for compute functionality, so the problem is no doubt there. But how do I make glew understand it has the 1.11 libs? It probably has the correct .c files in the library, but glew thinks it cant use them